# How to git clone a repo in windows from other pc within the LAN?

Tags: windows, git, repository, clone, lan

I have this git repo "c:/xampp/htdocs/****" in my main PC and its IP address is 192.168.0.6. Now I want to git clone this repo from ubuntu-server which running on a Vmware Player in my main PC.

I did

```
 git clone \\192.168.0.6\c:\xampp\htdocs\****
```

and

```
 git clone //192.168.0.6/c:/xampp/htdocs/****
```

from ubuntu-server and neither worked.

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir '****'.: Permission denied
```

What did I wrong?
what should I do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To access the repo, you must either share it on `192.168.0.6` or must be the same domain user as the one that owns the file on `192.168.0.6`.

If you share the directory on `192.168.0.6` (e.g. with share name `myrepo`), you access it with `//192.168.0.6/myrepo`.

If you are logged in on your box with a user accout that is known on `192.168.0.6`, you could try accessing the repo through the administrative shares:

```
//192.168.0.6/c$/xampp/htdocs/...
```

Always use forward slashes.

Another alternative would be using SSH to access the remote machine.

Answer (score 40):

You should use the command `git daemon` to host your repo, like this:

In your computer that will act as a server:

`git daemon --base-path=<path_to_folder_containing_project_folder> --export-all`

(please note that `path_to_folder_containing_project` is the folder containing your projects folders, it will provide all projects under that folder)

In your client:

`git clone git://<local ip>/<project name>`

The cloned repo will have its origin pointing to the server in your LAN, so you may want to use `git remote set-url origin` to point it to the original origin.

You may want to run `git daemon` with the `--verbose` option to get more details in case you run into problems.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. For clarity you might consider re-phrasing `<path_to_projects_folder>` as `<path_to_folder_containing_project>`.

Comment: I got the following issue (even after pruning/updating all branches), after receiving all objects: `fatal: read error: Invalid argument` & `fatal: error in sideband demultiplexer`

Comment: @DrumM did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647179/git-daemon-clone-is-not-working-in-local-area-network   ??

Comment: Pass `--base-path=.` if just one repo needs to be shared. At the client side don't give any sub-path in the URL; just give a directory name for the cloned repo: `git clone git://<LOCAL_IP>/ DIR_NAME` (mind the space between `/` and the directory name).

Comment: Many thanks for that! Worked flawlessly. To be mentioned, for Windows for the "path_to_folder_containing_project" I used the Windows path syntax like "C:/folder1/subfolder2" etc and it worked perfectly. Before actually trying, I was unsure if I need to use a Linux-style or Windows-style path there.

Comment: Instead of `<LOCAL_IP>` you can use the network name of the source PC

Answer (score 26):

Make sure that your c:/xampp/htdocs folder (or sub folders of it) is shared in windows, so you can navigate on the network by this address:

```
\\192.168.0.6\htdocs
```

Then you clone by using file:////. Note that there are **four** slashes:

```
git clone file:////192.168.0.6/htdocs/somerepo.git
```

Answer (score 3):

Using explorer (smb) to mount the remote repository as a network share is the easiest way. I'm not entirely sure, but I think you paths might be wrong. Try `file:///192.168.0.6\c:\xampp...` instead.

There are two things that might have gone wrong for you:

- You don't have read permission on the remote repository
- You don't have write permission in the location you want to create your repository ( the current working directory or the directory you specify as second argument to git clone)

And also check if your samba server works for normal file access.

Answer (score 3):

To make git repo on Windows local network you'd need to do the following:

1. Create new repo

   git init --bare projectName.git
2. Share this folder (projectName.git) with the users you need
3. Find your PC ip with ipconfig command (e.g. 192.168.2.101)
4. Run this command from some user's machine

   git clone //192.168.2.101/projectName.git

Note: open \\192.168.2.101 in finder to see the correct path to the projectName.git (e.g. //192.168.2.101/some/path/projectName.git)

Comment: Thank you for including the `--bare` parameter, this makes a lot of sense now. My only question is if you've already set up the "remote" repo can you get away with using this command on the "local" machine `git clone //192.168.2.101/.git`

Comment: @tisaconundrum Where is the `remote` repo? On the network drive or in some folder on the same machine you wish to run `git clone`?

Comment: @tisaconundrum If on a network drive, use `ping [network drive name] -4` to get the network drive's IP address and then use `git clone [networkdriveIP]\\Path\\To\\GitBareRepo` from the location you want to clone `GitBareRepo` into. I'm using windows shell and hence the double backslashes -- substitute them for forward slashes if you're on a unix system.

Comment: @tisaconundrum If `remote` repo is on the machine containing the location to which you want to clone that remote repo (i.e., the remote and soon-to-be-created `local` repo reside on the same machine) use `file://C:\\Path\\To\\GitBareRepo`.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance @MTV. I ended up answering my own question by trying this. It does make a clone of the repository even when a name is not present at the beginning of the `.git`

Comment: @MTV thank you very much. I cloned a git repository on windows server like this: `git clone \\CompanyServer\Users\Gilbert\Documents\Projects\Myapp myapp-local-copy` The entire path can be obtained by navigating to the repository's folder starting from the Networks tab in file manager. The user cloning must also have permissions to that folder. So you can right click the folder, go to properties -> security and add the user.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this error while trying to clone a repository in a remote pc to a local pc within the same LAN network.
The solution was to first make sure the drive location in the remote pc had the correct access rights for the local PC(Read/Write-which can be set using windows sharing options)
Copy the path of the remote repository. In your local pc paste the path in a windows explorer window. Then copy its directory address and paste it into any browser. 
Now you should get a link with the hostname and the correct cloning URL format.
Use this link to clone the repository in the local pc.

Hope this helps. 
Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

"I have a few **different computers** that I use at home and I wanted to set up GIT that I can access my code from any of them. It took me a bit because I was too used to working with a client-server model where I designate one machine as the "server" that holds the repository and everything else was a client. Instead, GIT seems to operate more like a merge tool and every local copy is its own "master." Once I understood that, it turns out that setting up GIT is very simple and just needs GIT itself and SSH".

To read more you can check this link:
http://blog.lazyhacker.com/2010/04/setting-up-git-for-home-network.html