# How to use HTTPS protocol instead of SSH in GIT server in Local?

Tags: git, networking, ssh, https

All I was trying to set up a GIT server in my local machine and to clone the repository from another machine in my local network(My both machine are running on  Windows 10). I want to use **HTTPS** protocol instead of **SSH**. How Can I change from **SSH** to **HTTPS**?

Your Help is welcomed and thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need a git server on a local machine?

Comment: I think I understand... to use HTTPS instead of SSH change the remote URL to `https://`.

Comment: There is no need for any changes in GIT bash for changing to `https://`?.If there any, please Convey

Comment: no, Git bash is just a command line shell, not git itself.

Comment: For cloning my local repository in the server machine to another machine via LAN how to do it without ssh?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200181/how-to-git-clone-a-repo-in-windows-from-other-pc-within-the-lan, or https://serverfault.com/questions/463811/git-clone-pull-across-local-network