# git clone command file://

Tags: git, git-clone

I try to clone repository from a remote server using the command :

git clone file://ip_address/GIT_SERVER/test.git

and always get the following error:

fatal: '//ip_address/GIT_SERVER/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I create shared folder to the repository

any idea ?

Comment: if you are using an IP address, why do you use `file://` as a transport? `file://` is used for things that are present on the FS.

Comment: Are you trying to access a network share in your local network?

Comment: @eftshift0  Can us show me some link example with file:// ?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález González yes

Comment: what? It is not about me telling you how to use `file://` but rather _how do your reach the repo you mean to clone?_. Where is it? Is it in the File System?

Comment: [How to git clone a repo in windows from other pc within the LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200181/how-to-git-clone-a-repo-in-windows-from-other-pc-within-the-lan)?

Comment: @eftshift0 `file://ip_address/` is valid both syntactically and semantically: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Comment: OK.... this is news to me.... I had always assumed that it would _always_ be used for stuff in the local FS.

Comment: Just in case, I have no idea how that should work if you are pointing to a remote host _specially_ if on a `*NIX` host.... _but_ at least I stand corrected in the sense that it is _valid_.